# How to include asset files in a .NET Standard 2.0 library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, csproj, .net-standard

I'm migrating a UWP class library to a .NET Standard 2.0 library and I'm having some issues getting some asset files I have in the library.

I've included them in the library project, under a folder called "Dictionaries", and I've set them to be included in the output folder. My library .csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="Dictionaries\EN.lst">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    <ItemGroup>
    ...
```

The issue I have is that I'm referencing this lib from a UWP application, and the folder with these assets is not copied into the output AppX folder, but only inside the parent Debug folder. I mean, when I compile in Debug mode I get something like this:

- bin

  - x86

    - Debug

      - AppX
      - **Dictionaries**
      - ...

Now, the AppX folder is the only folder that is distributed to a device when it installs the app, and therefore the library .dll file itself is contained within that AppX folder. Same goes for the Assets folder of the main application.

I know how to get the path to the executing .dll:

```
new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath
```

And I'd expect that Dictionaries folder to be in the same folder as the .dll file, within the parent AppX folder, but this is not the case here, so at the end of the story I can't consume those asset files I need in the library.

***Note***: since I know their location I know I could just use the right path, but the thing is that unless those files are actually inside the AppX folder, they won't be included in the final .appx file that will be distributed to the users.

Am I missing something obvious here, is there a way to specify those asset files to be copied in the actual folder of the compiled app (the AppX folder)?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**:

You could add some commands to your postbuild events to handle the copy to output manually.

```
mkdir $(TargetDir)\AppX\Dictionaries
xcopy /y $(ProjectDir)Dictionaries\EN.lst $(TargetDir)AppX\Dictionaries
```

Basically it creates a directory `Dictionaries` in your `AppX` folder and then copies your EN.lst there

**Edit**: i came up with another solution where you won't need postbuild events.

**Method 2**:

Since you're looking into the `.csproj` file you can also add a small line into `<Content>` Tag:

```
<Content Include="Dictionaries\EN.lst">
    <Link>AppX\Dictionaries\EN.lst</Link>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>          
</Content>
```

This would also let you rename the .lst data if you'd like to.

Be aware that if you do Method 2 that the file will disapear from the solution folder. As a workaround for that you can add it a second time to the project. You would have somtehing like

```
<Content Include="Test\Data.xml">
  <Link>Test\renamed.xml</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
<Content Include="Test\Data.xml">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

in your `.csproj` file afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, even though I'm not sure if it's the right solution in my case, I mean, I wouldn't want to mess with the default UWP compilation toolchain as I've already had tons of issues with it in the past without even changing anything.

Comment: @Sergio0694 i've updated my answer, with a second method, may this suit yoú better :)